# Nokia5110 LCD user's manual

Tags: stm32, lcd

I am confused when searching for a user's manual for Nokia5110 LCD. I've found [User manual ET LCD5110](http://skpang.co.uk/catalog/images/lcd/graphic/docs/User_Manual_ET_LCD5110.pdf) with
This has the same pins with different placement; therefore I don't know whether I have found the relevant user's manual.
My own LCD is the following:

[image]

Comment: you posted a broken link ... also, you did not ask a question

Comment: @Bornak, please use the link button to add a pretty link.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth:

in this link: https://www.bluetin.io/displays/nokia-5110-display-raspberry-pi-guide/ the same display as you is being used.

At the end, there is in Buying Featured Items - Adafruit a link added (named Nokia 5110/3310 monochrome LCD + extras), the link is:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/338

This link shows a different pin-assigned board, but it seems functionally similar (at least you can check both pages).